# ul li nested class jquery hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, nested-class, jquery-hover

I am trying to add mouse hover effect to a list having nested classes but no luck so far even after spending so many hours.

HTML:

```
<div class="pricing-wrap">
 <ul class="pricing_main">
  <li class="pricing pricing_three main">
    <h2>Used Containers</h2>
    .....
  </li>
  <li class="pricing pricing_three normal">
    <h2>Used Containers</h2>
    .....
  </li>
  <li class="pricing pricing_three normal">
    <h2>Used Containers</h2>
    .....
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

...and here is the jquery I am trying to use for mouse hover

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".pricing-wrap ul.pricing_main").hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).find('li.pricing_three').addClass("main");
      },
      function () {
        jQuery(this).find('li.pricing_three').removeClass("normal");
      }
    );
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.pricing-wrap{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    margin:20px 0 30px 0;
    float:left;
}

.pricing_main{
    overflow:hidden;
    float:none;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    width:100.5%;
    padding:7px 0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
}

li.pricing{
    padding:0;
    margin:20px 0 20px -1px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center !important;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    position:relative;
}

li.main{
    margin:0 0 0 -1px;
    -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow:  0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index:1;
}

li.pricing:first-child{
    margin-left:0;
}

li.pricing ul li{ padding:8px 0; margin:0 35px; border-top:1px dotted #eee;}

li.pricing ul li:first-child{border-top:none;}

li.pricing h2{
    background:#ddd;
    padding:10px 0;
    margin:0;
    font-size:20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    font-weight:bold;
}

li.main h2{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:21px 1px;
    margin:-1px -1px 0 -1px;
    border-bottom:none;
}

li.main{
    border-color:#ccc;
}

.plan-head{ background:#f9f9f9; padding:20px 0 15px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #eee;}

.plan-price{ font-size:25pt; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:-2px; line-height:1;}

.plan-bottom{ background:#f9f9f9; padding:15px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #eee;}

li.main .plan-bottom{padding:35px 0;}

.plan-bottom{ background:#f9f9f9; padding:25px 0; border-top:1px solid #eee;}

.plan-bottom a{ font-weight:bold; padding:8px 15px; background:#000; color:#fff !important; font-size:14px; opacity:.9}

li.main .plan-bottom a{padding:13px 22px; opacity:1}

.plan-bottom a:hover,
li.main .plan-bottom a:hover{}

li.pricing_three{
    width:33%;
}

li.pricing_four{
    width:24.7%;
}
```

You can check this live at www.modcansolutions.ca/#pricing

Any quick help will be appreciated.

Many thanks,

~ Dipak G.

Comment: You're adding a class `main` and removing a class `normal`? why is that?

Comment: The link you provided is not working. Please create a jsfiddle. I recommand using [Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) for a better manipulation of your DOM. Also check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp) and [this](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Comment: add main and normal class css in css file....which is missing now

Comment: still link is not working.....dont waste time

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/tjpr8/) check this .....maybe u want something like this

Comment: @Prashant First, there is nothing to waste time. Second, thanks for making the fiddle, that's what I exactly mean. As you can see there are three tabs and what I want is to add hover effects per tab. Possible to have each one of these magnify and highlight once mouse is hovered over top?

Comment: ok i got your question....
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/tjpr8/1/)
this your answer

Comment: Check if [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tCEbn) helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".pricing.pricing_three").hover(function() {
                jQuery(this).addClass("main").removeClass("normal");
            },
                    function() {
                        jQuery(this).removeClass("main");
                    });

        });
```

Comment: @DipakG. My answer and his answer is same. Please check my jsfiddle link in below answer.

Comment: @Prashant Your answer and Maulik's answer isn't same. I agree that you'r code works very well in jsfiddle but Maulik's code is better which replaces class NORMAL with class MAIN on hover. Any ways, many thanks for your help and efforts.

Comment: @Prashant How can I keep the default (first tab) intact on mouse out? If you check your jsfiddle, when you hover and out first tab, it loses the default background and all 3 tabs looks the same. Default tab: http://imgur.com/kNuxTEv. Tabs after mouse out on first (default) tab : http://imgur.com/4wCCxQ3

Answer (score 0):

your answer

> `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
>       jQuery(".pricing").hover(function () {
>           jQuery(this).addClass("main");
>         },
>         function () {
>           jQuery(this).removeClass("main");
>         }
>       );
>   });`

or you can check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/tjpr8/1/)

Comment: if u got your answer then vote up answer. by clicking arrow up. Please do that. Your site is not opening.